# Array index out of bound exception in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I have a group of buttons like 48 of them.

In the form load event, I take all the button text values from each button to run a query, which is done using "for loop and array".

This is my work so far.

```
Button[] btnarray = { button1, button2, button3, button5, button6};

for (int j = 0; j <= btnarray.Length; j++)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    string query = "SELECT carplate FROM billing WHERE carplate='" + btnarray[j].Text + "' AND dates=DATE(NOW())"; // This is where i get error.

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        btnarray[j].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        btnarray[j].BackColor = Color.Khaki;
    }                
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is incorrect you should compare to `<` the length not `<=` the length:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < btnarray.Length; j++)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexes of `Array` are from 0 to array size - 1. Switch the loop to

```
for (int j = 0; j < btnarray.Length; j++)
```

Or

```
for (int j = 0; j <= btnarray.Length - 1; j++)
```

First option is better since it saves the `btnarray.Length - 1` calculation every iteration.